# Missing /dev/log?

Tags: 20.04

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 (via WSL2) and `/dev/log` is missing and creates issues when trying to use openvpn:

```
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

What package(s) can I install to fix the problem?

```
> lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: Is the `systemd-journald` service running (ex. `systemctl status systemd-journald`)?

Comment: I get this error: `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`
I am using Ubuntu on WSL2 if that helps.

Comment: Ah I suspected that you were using WSL - that would have been useful information to include in your question. I don't know how to get openvpn to work around that - sorry

Comment: Sorry about that, I added this information. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, might be helpful for you -

The logging service is not started by default. So let's start it with

```
sudo service rsyslog start
```

After that you should have `/var/log/syslog`. Check with

```
ls /var/log/syslog
```

Of course, if you don't have `rsyslog`, run

```
sudo apt install rsyslog
```

to install it.